# How young can astronauts realistically be in the 2040-2050's?

Tags: technology, space, space-travel, travel

With the return of space odysseys and a boom for space studies, could future astronauts be taught since primary school and therefore be sent to space in their late teens (after one ultra last intensive prep year)?

How fast do you think a "full" astronaut formation program could take?

Comment: What's an astronaut?  By 2040, most manned space launches may be private.  Are their crew astronauts?  What about the passengers?  I wouldn't expect people to become astronauts (as in employees of NASA working in space) quicker than people can become airplane pilots.  As such, teens seems a bit aggressive.

Comment: Adding to the above, without artificial gravity you may find that anyone who is too young (under 20 at least) may have issues if they grow in space, as muscle atrophy and [other side-effects become issues for astronauts](http://www.racetomars.ca/mars/article_effects.jsp). This is,  of course, hard to judge... We haven't sent any kids to space that I know of.

Comment: How is this related to world building?

Comment: What is this, a twist on *Ender's Game*?

Comment: Once you can sustain full-time life with dependents on your ship or space colony they can be there from birth while their parents are the astronauts.

Comment: @Brythan I was going for crew astronauts indeed. Not kids in space from birth nor for recreation

Comment: Keep in mind that astronauts are not just (nor necessarily) pilots - they are, firstly and foremost, researchers. Today, they need at least a Bachelor degree before being able to candidate themselves for a spot on a spaceship.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your question: Depends.

But I always like to answer the question of **how to make young astronauts possible in space**

- Make space exploration very popular and favorite
- Make astronauts into celebrities
- Basically, make it as popular as if it is ice hockey, football (or soccer, or both :) ), or baseball

In that case 6 year old kid training hard to become astronaut would be no surprise, as it is with same age kids training hard to be once popular sport hero.

In real world, you enter this popular area around age 18, so teenage astronauts would be possible.

And drawback on body would be accepted the same, as if ice hockey player damages his body just for purpose of the game

Comment: These 3 points are sound , I was thinking along those lines too . A space rush would definitely work things out

Comment: There is currently a "Train Like an Astronaut" program to teach fitness and healthy habits, aimed at kids. A presentation cycles on the NASA channel, and you can find the video.

Comment: You're missing the reason that current astronauts are not young. Space, under current technology, is lethally unforgiving of rash or impulsive behavior, and this pretty much defines teenagers Not only do teenagers get themselves in trouble on a regular basis, they mess up the equipment they're riding in, and with the current costs of space launches this is not what you call a good idea. Sending teenagers into space would be a great way to get whole shiploads of people in trouble. Unless, of course, you can improve the technology so much that you don't need astronauts..

Comment: It's good to notice that astronauts need a bachelor degree before going to space. The same isn't true for hockey players.

Comment: @ThalesPereira - Hockey players go to space? Cool! How many goals do they score?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast You got me there.

Answer (score 1):

Depends entirely on the needs and the social norms. There have been 14 year olds and younger fighting in wars, so if the need is great enough, they can go to space too. There have been [11 year olds flying fighter jets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katrina_Mumaw).

Currently we do require an extensive education and training, because we can - supply and demand. There are far more than enough very well educated 30 year olds eager to go to space, and an astronaut costs peanuts compared to the ground crew and equipment anyway, so the better trained candidate is selected.

If space flight becomes cheap and plentiful enough that astronauts are in high demand, and reliable enough that astronauts are not more than glorified factory workers, then you really don't need all that much training anymore. Realistically in a first step the job requirements should become comparable to that of commercial airline pilots [which can be as young as 21](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/travel_news/article-2759478/His-career-really-taking-British-Airways-hands-high-flying-21-year-old-dream-job-pilot-passengers-think.html).

Answer (score 1):

While "being an astronaut" sounds wickedly "fun", we should remember what exactly those guys up there do.

"Being an astronaut" is not exactly a job - they are, before anything, researchers. They are really intelligent people that work to push science further. They aren't up there just hanging out in space, they are actively making science happen. What we call an astronaut today would be more precisely called "researcher in space".

So, if you want to become an astronaut, you need a bit more than physical fitness. You need to be able to contribute to the research in a sensible, significant way to make the cost to launch you up there worthwhile. Today, by the current NASA standards, you need to have at least a major on one of a few select field to be even elegible to be sent to space.

While your teenagers can be phisically fit, it is really improbable that they can contribute to any kind of research before college - except maybe studies to check what happens when you get drunk or mate in space.

Answer (score 0):

There definitely is a lower limit to how young.

Firstly, there are legal considerations to be aware of. You probably can't send minors in space, and you probably can't employ them to be astronauts anyways. Cultural acceptability will also factor in.

Secondly, kids in development might experience some weird stuff if they don't have their daily dose of gravity. To my knowledge, we don't know what happens really, so unless you want to find out you'll have to wait until the kids are fully grown.

Presumably, you want your astronauts to survive, so the only hard requirement left is not turning into jelly on take-off, on landing or in space, aka good physical condition.

If you tick all the boxes, I can't see reasons you can't have young astronauts. You can give them proper training as they grow up, so that's hardly a barrier.